# How to get Datefield value in EXTJS in yyyymmdd format

Tags: extjs

I am using a datefield with y/m/d format. When I call getSubmitData()  method on this datefield it returns me the date value like  ‘14/05/16’. Is there any way to convert this value  to  ‘20140516’.If i give the format as ymd, it shows me  the selected date in the datefield in 140516 format,which i want to be shown as 2014/05/16.Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Ext.Date.parse(getSubmitData(), "Y-m-d")) I think

Comment: thanks...Actually i tried using Ext.Date.parse("11/04/14", "Y-m-d"); but this gives me undefined.Is there any other way?

Comment: you should do something like var dt = new Date('11/04/14') then Ext.Date.format(dt, 'Y-m-d')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [submitFormat:'ymd'](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-submitFormat) config option.

Comment: thanks....this worked!!!.But it shows date like 140517 and i need it as 20140517.How can this be done?

Comment: You can find the available date format codes here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Date It should be 'Ymd'